# Влияет ли наличие SSL-сертификата на SEO статичного веб-сайта?

Tags: seo

Учитывают ли сейчас поисковики при ранжировании наличие SSL-сертификата у сайта без серверной логики?

Comment: На счет seo и поисков не знаю. Но как бы поисковик узнал есть серверная логика или нет ? Так что они не смогут делить сайты по такому критерию и если ssl считают плюсом, то это должно работать для любых видов сайта

Comment: Без ssl сайт будет просто считаться небезопасным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [руководстве по оптимизации Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/beginner/seo-starter-guide#appearance) рекомендует использовать https везде где возможно. Поэтому считаю что лучше выполнить рекомендацию. Тем более, что поставить сертификат LetsEncrypt ничего не стоит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]